# KSoap2 Android Consuming WCF giving Error

Tags: android, wcf

I have trying to consume `WCF` service using `KSoap2 3.4.0` in Android.

`Service` is hosted at http://cloudypost.com/StockListsWS.svc and it has one method `SayHi`, which can be accessed by http://cloudypost.com/StockListsWS.svc/Sayhi/Manish

I'm trying to consume this in my Android code.

```
private void SendRegIDToDB() {
         String METHOD_NAME = "SayHi";
         String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
         String URL = "http://cloudypost.com/StockListsWS.svc";
         String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/SayHi";

        try {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            // 2. Define the property
            PropertyInfo property = new PropertyInfo();
            //property.setNamespace("http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/"); // namespace to ensure that the element-name is prefixed with the namespace
            property.setName("name"); // name of the argument as per wsdl document
            property.setValue("manish"); // value of the property
            request.addProperty(property);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

            //to get the data
            String resultData = result.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

let me know whats wrong in above code.

Answer (score 1):

Your `http://cloudypost.com/StockListsWS.svc` my friend is not aligning with `SOAP` guidelines. Try to import your project 2 `wsdls` below into `SoapUI` and you will see that it cannot pull any APIs stubs.

> http://cloudypost.com/StockListsWS.svc?wsdl
>
> http://cloudypost.com/StockListsWS.svc?singleWsdl

Now you try with any up and running `Web Service` from http://www.service-repository.com/ and try creating a new project in `SoapUI` with its `xyz?wsdl` and you will see the difference.

[image]

Its not problem with your client code but issue is definitely with your `web service`

Comment: I also guess so..but Service seems to be working fine.may be the issue in configuration.I will create a new Test service and see if its working or not..